# How to add video using wpf visual studio?

Tags: wpf

I want my software to start with a short video introduction. Any tips on how to do that or if I should be using something other than WPF?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the MediaElement class.

http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/audio-video/playing-video/

Alternatively, an easier method is to launch a web browser and link to a youtube video like this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("path_to_youtube_video");
```